# Observable nested callbacks

Tags: typescript, rxjs, observable

I have a relatively complex nested observable that switches to other observables and needs the info returned from each previous observable. Something like:

```js
of(1).pipe(
  switchMap(res =>
    of(2).pipe(
      switchMap(res2 =>
        of(3).pipe(
          switchMap(res3 => {
              console.log(res)
              console.log(res2)
              console.log(res3)
              return of()
            }
          )
        )
      )
    )
  )
)
```

Is there a way to accomplish this without the nested callbacks of the switchmaps? The main issue is having to remember the value emitted from each nested observable.

Comment: Do you really need the value of the parent observables? For this particular case, I'd argue you only need the first since all other values are derived from the first. Could you provide a more representative example of your problem? If you need them all and they're all entirely independent observables, you could use `combineLatest` or something.

Comment: I've updated the example but the concept remains the same. It's really just the issue of the nested callbacks.

Answer (score 3):

Sure. All you need to do is to reemit the previous values:

```
of(1).pipe(
  switchMap(res => of({ res1: res, res2: 2 })),
  switchMap(res => of({ ...res, res3: 3 })
).subscribe(...)
```

or

```
of(1).pipe(
  switchMap(res1 => of(2).pipe(map(res2 => ({ res1, res2 }))),
  switchMap(res => of(3).pipe(map(res3 => ({ ...res, res3 })))
).subscribe(...)
```

Comment: Is this a common practice? This seems like a cleaner solution than the nested piping to me, but I wonder if others might find this practice more complex.

Answer (score 0):

I think this can do the job:

```js
of(1).pipe(
  switchMap(res => forkJoin(of(res), of(2))), // Returns [1, 2]
  switchMap(res => forkJoin(...res.map(v => of(v)), of(3))), // forkJoin(of(1), of(2), of(3))
  switchMap(res => forkJoin(...res.map(v => of(v)), of(4))),
).subscribe(console.log) // 1, 2, 3, 4]
```